# Login page with tkinter and python for API to AWS cloud

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, authentication, screen

My code for login page not working , when i am calling the function 'HTTP_Connection' from button "open' on main page.

It will make connection to F5 device, syntax working fine, when i am giving 
input for a,b,c directly, from Tkinter i am trying to achieve .

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
root.title("Automated Configuration Manager")


def HTTP_Connection():
    a=et1.get()
    b=et2.get()
    c=et3.get()
    urllib3.disable_warnings()
    mgmt = ManagementRoot('a','b','c')
    ltm = mgmt.tm.ltm
    virtuals = mgmt.tm.ltm.virtuals
    virtual = mgmt.tm.ltm.virtuals.virtual


mainframe = Frame(root)
mainframe.grid(column=0,row=0, sticky=(N,W,E,S) )
mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
mainframe.pack(pady = 100, padx = 100)

#choices = { 'F5','A5A','PA' }
var = StringVar() 
popupMenu = OptionMenu(mainframe, var,'F5','A5A','PA')
Label(mainframe, text="Choose a Option").grid(row = 1, column = 1)
popupMenu.grid(row = 2, column =1)



l1 = Label(root, text = "Enter IP Address:")
l1.pack()
global et1
global et2
global et3
et1 = Entry(root, bd = 5)
et1.pack()
a=et1.get()

l2 = Label(root, text = "User Name:")
l2.pack()
et2 = Entry(root, bd=5)
et2.pack()
b=et2.get()

g=StringVar()
g="enter password:"
l3=Label(root, text = g)
l3.pack()
et3 = Entry(root, bd=5, show = "*")
et3.pack()

b = Button(root, text = "Open", bd =5,command=HTTP_Connection)
b.pack()



root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I don't understand what it is you're trying to achieve? Do you need your program to return three variables in a specific format inside of a function declaration?

Comment: Yes, The value i am typing in login page.

Comment: Where are the values declared in program and what function do you need them to be parameters of?

Comment: mgmt = ManagementRoot('13.126.108.12','admin','admin')  ,                      it is where, my input get mapped.  I done codes for login page, but dont know how to get the input with syntex

Comment: That doesn't help, I need to know where the user is entering these details in your program. You also don't declare `mgmt` anywhere in your program.

Comment: I am using mainframe = Frame(root) for main page, where i am getting user name and password and IP from as input what i am typing.

Comment: If you run my codes you get it, Sorry  i am not python expert. I am F5 Engineer , for which i am doing some API Kit to do automation. Excuse for mistakes in codes

Comment: You still aren't listening to what I'm saying. **Where** does the user input these things **specifically** and **what specifically** do you need to happen to the inputs?

Comment: There is button called  "b = Button(root, text = "Open", bd =5,command=new_window):     when user click on this, the inputs given in main frame, username and password and IP, should get map with   syntax below     mgmt = ManagementRoot('IP','username','password')

Comment: And what does that have to do with the question? What do you want to happen to the inputs?

Comment: give me 5 min, i am removing the unwanted codes in main question, so i can explain easily!

Comment: I done edit, pleaes  check now codes,

Comment: I am calling HTTP_Connection function with inputs what i am giving

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this function:

```
def HTTP_Connection():
    a=et1.get()
    b=et2.get()
    c=et3.get()
    urllib3.disable_warnings()
    mgmt = ManagementRoot('a','b','c')
    ltm = mgmt.tm.ltm
    virtuals = mgmt.tm.ltm.virtuals
    virtual = mgmt.tm.ltm.virtuals.virtual
```

You are declaring three variables `a`, `b` and `c` which you then don't use. Instead you are running `ManagementRoot('a','b','c')` which uses strings containing the values `"a"`, `"b"` and `"c"` instead of the variables you declared earlier.

You *should* be able to fix this by changing the line to the below:

```
    mgmt = ManagementRoot(et1.get(),et2.get(),et3.get())
```

Comment: Thanks, I will test it and confirm asap